# Apache connection Pool2 - POJO as key

Tags: java, connection-pooling

I have a connection factory extending BaseKeyedPooledObjectFactory. I would like to a POJO that will hold user's username and password as the key. It lets me borrow object just fine with the custom Credential POJO but throws a NullPointerException when returning the object to the pool. If I switch it to a key, then it can only do username and there is no way to pass the password down to the SomePOJO to create a connection.

I believe this may be the limitation of the connection pool or do I need to implement specific methods in my Credential object? Is there a method that I use where I can create SomePOJO without calling borrowObject and then add it to the pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by overriding equals and hashCode methods in my POJO object that I'm using as a key.